# Firebase Google authentication forbidden (permission denied)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am currently using firebase to trying authenticate users with google.
I set up an angular project with my project1.
While signing in anonymously into firebase, everything works as expected,
if i change to signing in with google using the popup, it just breaks with the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer https://project1.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=SECRET&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=7.13.2&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.TVMmU0ureXg.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNEZ47O4XPxvOHlE2OsKBWeCQxiEw%2Fm%3D__features__ are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer https://project1.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=SECRET&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=7.13.2&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.TVMmU0ureXg.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNEZ47O4XPxvOHlE2OsKBWeCQxiEw%2Fm%3D__features__ are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

If i change my firebaseConfig from project1 to project2 (options like Google auth enabled, etc. are the same) it works properly. Hence it can't be a client-issue. Same error occurs by running locally and hosting by firebase.

I have absolutely no clue why is that, i am sure there has to be something obvious in the firebase settings which i just can't figure out yet. As far as i can tell, i changed all kinds of options on the firebase-platform itself.

Comment: Sounds like you need to allow  that redirect in your google app.  Can you post the code you are using to do the google auth and the setup for your google app without the keys?  Is the domain authorized under google in authentication in the firebase console?

Comment: The redirect as well as the domain is allowed (using a second firebase project, google-login works fine) I just swap the firebase project and it stops working. But sure i will post my code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
Go to [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs -> Select your project and add a 'Authorised redirect URI':

'[https://myproject.web.app/**/auth/handler**](https://myproject.web.app/__/auth/handler)'
or 
'[https://myproject.firebaseapp.com//auth/handler](https://myproject.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler)'

Comment: I have the same problem with URLs all setup but the same  403 for a production domain...